# remove value from picklist at the point of creating new record

Tags: picklist

I have the following setting for my picklist.

```
No  Not Checked Assigned dynamically
Yes Not Checked Assigned dynamically
```

**I don't have default value.**

But the problem is whenever the new record is created, the value for that picklist is set to [No].

At the first point of creating record, there should be no value for that picklist. That picklist is optional for the sub stages.

**How can I remove inserting [No] value when a new record is created?** I didn't set default value, so feel quite weird.

Comment: Do you have some active Record Types for this object?

Comment: I think that is some bugs of salesforce. I think the setting is cached for some time. Yesterday I face that error. Today when I create new record, it is created with No Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is some bugs of salesforce. I think the setting is cached for some time. Yesterday I face that error. Today when I create new record, it is created with No Value.